# ImageView.setImage axes parameter does not switch X-Y dimensions

Tags: pyqtgraph

I have modified the ImageView example by adding the statement `data[:, ::10, :] = 0`, which sets every tenth element of the middle dimension to 0. The program now shows horizontal lines. This is consistent with the documentation of the [ImageView.setImage](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/imageview.html?highlight=imageview#pyqtgraph.ImageView.setImage) function: the default axes dictionary is `{'t':0, 'x':1, 'y':2, 'c':3}`. However, when I change this to `{'t':0, 'x':2, 'y':1, 'c':3}`, nothing changes where I would expect to get vertical rows.

So my question is: how can I give the row dimension a higher precedence in PyQtGraph? Of course I can transpose all my arrays myself before passing them to the `setImage` function but I prefer not to. Especially since both Numpy and Qt use the row/column convention and not X before Y. I don't see why PyQtGraph chooses the latter.

For completeness, find my modified ImageView example below.

```
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Create window with ImageView widget
win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
win.resize(800,800)
imv = pg.ImageView()
win.setCentralWidget(imv)
win.show()
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ImageView')

## Create random 3D data set with noisy signals
img = pg.gaussianFilter(np.random.normal(size=(200, 200)), (5, 5)) * 20 + 100
img = img[np.newaxis,:,:]
decay = np.exp(-np.linspace(0,0.3,100))[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
data = np.random.normal(size=(100, 200, 200))
data += img * decay
data += 2

## Add time-varying signal
sig = np.zeros(data.shape[0])
sig[30:] += np.exp(-np.linspace(1,10, 70))
sig[40:] += np.exp(-np.linspace(1,10, 60))
sig[70:] += np.exp(-np.linspace(1,10, 30))

sig = sig[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * 3
data[:,50:60,50:60] += sig

data[:, ::10, :] = 0 # Make image a-symmetrical

## Display the data and assign each frame a time value from 1.0 to 3.0
imv.setImage(data, xvals=np.linspace(1., 3., data.shape[0]), 
             axes={'t':0, 'x':2, 'y':1, 'c':3}) # doesn't help

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking through [ImageView.py, `setImage()`](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/imageview/ImageView.py#L201) parses the axes dictionary and based on presence of 't' it builds the z-axis/frame slider, and that's it. Rearranging the axes seems **unimplemented** yet.